# How to fork/duplicate a stream

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, bacon.js

I have an `outer` stream. I want to use this stream in two different ways.
First way is to just listen on values.
Second way is to build a new stream with `flatMapConcat`.

But I can't do both at once. I think I have to fork or duplicate the stream.

I've tried adding a bus but it doesn't work.

```
var outer = Bacon.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);


// 1.way build a new stream
var combined = outer.flatMapConcat(function(v) {
  return Bacon.sequentially(1000, ["a" + v, "b" + v]);
});


// 2. way use the plain stream
// outer.onValue(function(v) { console.log(v); });

// Tried to insert a bus
var forkBus = new Bacon.Bus();

forkBus.plug(outer);

forkBus.onValue(function(v) {
console.log('outer side' + v);
});

combined.take(3).log();
```

How can I fork/duplicate a stream so I can use it in two different ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`.onValue(f)`](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#stream-onvalue) registers a subscriber to the event stream, and because your stream is already buffered and ready in your example (since you used `fromArray()`), the stream immediately gets dispatched to the new subscriber and is consumed to its end. The same issue results if you try to setup the `combined` stream and call `.log()` on it first.

The docs for [`Bacon.fromArray()`](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bacon-fromarray) hints at this:

> creates an EventStream that delivers the given series of values (given
>   as array) **to the first subscriber**. The stream **ends** after these values
>   have been delivered.

In reality, if your event stream is coming from something continuous / stochastic (like user input or click events), your code will generally be able to setup a stream with as many subscribers or sub-streams as it needs *before any events actually occur*, like so:

```
var outer = $('#some-number-input').asEventStream('input')...;

outer.onValue(function(v) { console.log(v); });

var combined = outer.flatMapConcat(function(v) {
    return Bacon.sequentially(1000, ["a" + v, "b" + v]);
});

combined.take(3).log();

// After this point, any event that occurs in `outer` will pass
// through both functions
```

If you want to do some action on a stream without modifying it (and without registering a subscriber, which would consume the stream), you can use [`doAction`](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#observable-doaction):

```
var outer = Bacon.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

var actioned = outer.doAction(function(v) {
    console.log(v);
});

var combined = actioned.flatMapConcat(function(v) {
    return Bacon.sequentially(1000, ["a" + v, "b" + v]);
});

combined.take(3).log();
```

Comment: You can also turn your example stream to async with a simple `.delay(0)`